# Is factory reset neccessary when updating cyanogenMod?

Tags: cyanogenmod, updates, twrp, rom-update

I have rooted my phone and have TWRP installed.

I am updating CyanogenMod 11 to 12.

Do I need to do a factory reset/ Clear data partition to proceed or can I do without it?

Comment: Well, I would say its not like Kind of a thing which needs to be done inorder to proceed but rather than its like it's always advised to make sure that you don't ran onto trouble as sometimes because of the junk folder you ended up in something where you don't want to be !

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is always recommended to do an factory reset and wipe cache data after every update or change of firmware to avoid problems.

You will **lose** all your data anyway so right after flash your new firmware, reboot the phone. You don't say your phone so just do as usual do the factory reset wipe cache reboot it again then done wouldn't spend more than 5 minutes.